# Excel: Check if cell string value exists in column, and get all cell references to that string

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I suspect this may be a job for VBA, which is beyond my abilities. But here's the scenario:

Column A in Sheet 1 (CAS1) contains x rows of text values

Column A in Sheet 2 (CAS2) contains x rows of text values

Part A - For each row value in CAS1, I need to know if the string is contained in any of the cells in CAS2. Not exact match, the string can be only part of the searched cells.

Part B - I need to know the cell value of each cell in CAS2 that contains the CAS1 value (if they do exist, they can be listed in the cells adjacent to the cell being searched in CAS1).

I've tried the following to attempt Part A, all to no avail:

```
vlookup(A1,sheet2!A:A,1,false)
NOT(ISNA(MATCH(A1,sheet2!A:A,0)))
ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,sheet2!A:A,0))
COUNTIF(sheet2!A:A,A1)>0 
IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,sheet2!A:A, 0)), "No Match", "Match")
```

I know some of the cell values in CAS2 contain the cell values in CAS1, so I don't know why they return false or No Match. I suspect it may be down to the nature of the text content. So here's some sample data:

**CAS1**

```
LQ056
RV007H
RV008
RV009H
TSN304
TSN305
```

**CAS2**

```
RV009-satin-nickel-CO.jpg
STR314.jpg
STR315.jpg
HCY001.jpg
RV008-oval-rad-CO.jpg
HCY001-BRAC006.jpg
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be faced through VBA (at least, I imagine the VBA solution much more easily than the possible Excel one). You need a macro that, for each row in CAS1, search the content in each row of CAS2 and returns you the address.

```
For Each cell In Sheets("CAS1").Range("A1:A" & Sheets("CAS1").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row) '<-- check each cell of the range A1:A? of sheet CAS1 (adapt "A" and "1" if they're different)
    recFound = 0 '<-- count how many findings there are
    For Each cell2 In Sheets("CAS2").Range("A1:A" & Sheets("CAS2").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row) '<-- check in each cell of the range A1:A? of sheet CAS2 (adapt "A" and "1" if they're different)
        If InStr(cell2.Value, cell.Value) <> 0 Then '<-- if the value in cell is contained in the value in cell2..
            recFound = recFound + 1 '<-- account the new finding
            cell.Offset(0, recFound) = Split(cell2.Address, "$")(1) & Split(cell2.Address, "$")(2) '<--write the address on the right of the currently searched cell
        End If
    Next cell2
Next cell
```

All the above should be enclosed in a macro, e.g. `Sub makeMySearch()`, that should be run to get the results. As commented in my code, I'm assuming that data are in `A1:A?` of both sheets; but they of course might be, for example, in `B5:B?` of the sheet 1 and in `C7:C?` of the sheet 2. You need clearly to adapt the code to your current data.

Comment: IT WORKS! This is awesome. Bonus questions - 1. How do I get the actual value of the cell, rather than the cell address? (I know, I original request was worded incorrectly, sorry!), and 2. The words in each cell in CAS2 are separated by either a dash (-) or a space. Right now, a search for a text of BAT001 will return the cell that contains a text value of "TRBAT001-foo bar" (no quotes). I'd only want it to return the cell if it contained semi-exact, like "BAT001-foo bar". Hope that make sense, and many thanks for your help already

Comment: @user2565123, if you want to return the value of the cell, you just need to write `cell.Offset(0, recFound) = cell2.Value` instead of the `Split()` combination. However, I didn't understand well: if you search "AA" and you get "BBAACC", you want to return only "AACC"? In that case, that's string parsing: so you should close this question by accepting your favorite answer and post a new one (if you're unable to find a solution through existing threads).

Comment: Perfect! To re-explain what I meant - the macro will return any cell that has the CAS1 word **anywhere** within it's own string (so, searching for "BAT001" will return "TRBAT001-foo bar.jpg". However, I only want to return the cell if the cell string contains the exact word "BAT001" by itself e.g. "BAT001.jpg", or with any other words e.g. "BAT001-foo bar.png", **not** when the word forms part of another word. I'm sure the image .jpg or .png extension will add even more complications!

Comment: No problem! Again, many thanks for your help. No doubt this post will help others in the future

Comment: @user2565123 please accept one answer if the question is closed for you.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for VBA.  Some simple array-formulas can do the job.

To see if the entry in CAS1 is present in CAS2:

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,CAS2_)))
```

will return TRUE or FALSE.  **BUT** this formula has to be entered by holding down **CTRL-SHIFT** while hitting **ENTER**  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces **{...}** around the formula that you can see in the formula bar.

The SEARCH function returns an array of results, which will be either the #VALUE! error, or a number.

In order to return the address, the following **array-formula** can be entered adjacent to a cell in CAS1:

```
=IFERROR(ADDRESS(LARGE(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A2,CAS2_))*ROW(CAS2_),COLUMNS($A:A)),1),"")
```

Fill right for the maximum number of addresses possible, then select the group and fill down.

In this case, the array being returned is a string of either 0's, or 1 * the row number (i.e. the row number).  I assumend the data in CAS2 was in column A, but you can change the column number if needed (or even compute it if necessary, by replacing the `1` in the `ADDRESS` function with `COLUMN(CAS2_)`)

CAS1_ and CAS2_ are either named ranges, or absolute range references to the two text groups.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm keen to get this working, however, when I extrapolate the first formula down, the result is always false, even when I know this is not the case. Here's an example: In a cell in CAS1 contains RV008, and in CAS2 a cell contains RV008-oval-CO.jpg. But I still get a FALSE result?

Comment: @user2565123 Those are two examples that were in your posted sample and it works here.  Are you certain your cell references are correct?  Are you certain you entered it as an **array-formula** with **ctrl-shift-enter**?  If you look at the formula in the formula bar, do you see braces **{...}** around the formula?